# add an array to an array using arrayName[]= add_array without the index 0 in php

Tags: php, arrays, codeigniter

how can I add this array

```
    $triggers = [

    SMS_INVOICE => [
        'id' => 1,
        'name'        => 'Invoice Overdue Notice',
        'info'         => 'Trigger when invoice overdue notice is sent to customer contacts.',
    ]
```

this function without editing the function

```
   public function add_trigger($trigger)
{
   $this->triggers[] = $trigger;
}
```

the result will be

```
    array (size=10)
  'invoice_overdue_notice' => 
    array (size=3)
      'merge_fields' => 
        array (size=12)
          'id' => string '1' (length=1)
      'label' => string 'Invoice Overdue Notice' (length=22)
      'info' => string 'Trigger when invoice overdue notice is sent to customer contacts.' (length=65)
  'invoice_payment_recorded' =>
```

without `[0]` in front of it

Comment: You can do array_merge, to avoid numerical indexes in this case.

Comment: The function you say you are not editing uses [] to add to an array. That will use the next nonused integer, which will initially be zero. So, if you don't want zero, you need to edit that function.

Comment: okay notted @Tyralcori , that function is used for other actions. i was instructed not to modify it